How do you hide silicone caulk at a cabinet to countertop joint?
We recently painted our cabinets, and ended up with an ugly looking line at the clear caulk joint between the top of the cabinets the countertop. The brown is the old cabinet color showing through the clear silicone Any tips on how to clean this up a bit without cutting out the sealant and replacing? Was considering just running a paintable caulk over it but unsure if that is the best solution.


in general paint doesn't stick to silicone. there are some paint additives that can improve this a little.

Some paint primers will stick to silicone, though it can take a few coats. I'd try that first.
If that fails you'll need to cut and scrape away the silicone and re-caulk with something paintable. Don't expect new caulk to bond to silicone.
If all else fails, consider a small cove molding.

The cove molding probably the fastest and easiest.  No removing or hoping something might stick.  Paintable or make it an accent.

If the silicone is relatively new, a white silicone caulk may be able to be run over it and stick.  You might even be able to get a color that matches your paint even closer, but YMMV.  If not new, you probably have to bite the bullet and scrape the existing off.  Don't use silicone when you replace it.

What is relatively new? It's been on for about 3 months.
